# Is this standard OBJ/MTL spec?

Tags: texturing, uv, export

I have an OBJ mesh with UV coordinates ranging from 0 to 2 along both U, V dimensions.  I have four textures associated with this mesh.

The expected behavior is that the offset of the UV coordinates determines the specific texture to use.  For example, the UV coordinate (0.5, 0.5) refers to a coordinate in the first texture, (0.5, 1.5) is a UV coordinate in the second texture, (1.5, 0.5) is a coordinate in the third texture, and (1.5, 1.5) is a coordinate in the last texture.

However, I don't know if this is standard behavior, as many of the programs that I have tried using only texture UVs in the range (0, 0) < (u, v) < (1, 1), i.e. only the first texture is applied.

Comment: You could use a photo editing application and stitch all four textures together according to this UV map

Comment: Actually, I structured it to be multiple textures so that it would be easier to fit piecewise into memory.  Each individual texture is already huge (8192^2)